# Neumann derivative in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I would like to define the Neumann derivative for Lipschitz domains and $H^1$ functions, does this approach make sense, or do you see issues?

- let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ with distributional laplacian $\Delta u \in L^2$. It means that $\int_\Omega\nabla u \nabla v=\int_\Omega -\Delta u v$ for $v \in H^1_0$
- given an extension operator $E: H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)$ I define $\langle\partial_\nu u, \mu\rangle:=\int_\Omega\nabla u \nabla E\mu+\int_\Omega \Delta u E\mu$, for $\mu \in H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)$
- the definition is well posed: change the extension operator to $E'$ and we get $(E-E')(\mu)$ to have $0$ trace, so that by the first point, we get the same expression on the right hand side
- with trivial computations, $\partial_\nu: \{ u \in H^1, \Delta u \in L^2\}\rightarrow H^{-1/2}$ is linear, bounded, well defined

Is this a satisfactory definition or am I missing something/I did something wrong?

Comment: The extension operator should have $H^{1/2}$ as domain. Otherwise seems correct.

Comment: @daw Thank you for the feedback